# Minimum Elastic Beanstalk policy for upload & deploy

Tags: permissions, amazon-web-services, deployment, upload, elastic-beanstalk

I just created a new Elastic Beanstalk application called Chats.

I then created a IAM group called Chats.

Now, I want to give the Chats group a custom policy that is the most restrictive and only allows users in the Chats group to upload & deploy new Chats application versions.

Comment: I trust you've looked through the IAM documentation and figured out the appropriate ARNs, and such?

Comment: Using the api? Console? EB CLI? If you just use the api, you can be a lot more restrictive. But using the console/CLI you will need some more permissions in order for things to work right.